# How to make an extending robot arm with rigged hand attached to end?

Tags: rigging

I am modeling a character which has an extendable arm. However, I'm having trouble keeping a rigged hand at the end of the arm. I know I can use an array modifier, but it will not allow empty groups or armatures to be used as an end cap.

[image: arm]

This is what my current stuff is, I kept trying using curves and bendy bones but nothing is really  working for me. I'm kind of a newbie at blender so my bad if this is a simple solution!

PS. i think i should note that this is for animation!

Comment: Hello, if the arm is expandable, you could use this technic: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xKfdy050JMQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the technic explained [here](https://youtube.com/watch?v=xKfdy050JMQ), which is basically create your object, create a straight curve:

[image]

Give your object an *Array* modifier with *Fit Type > Fit Curve* and select the curve:

[image]

Give your object a *Curve* modifier with the curve as *Curve Object*:

[image]

Create a bone at the tip of the curve, select it in *Edit* mode, back to *Object* mode select the curve, switch to *Edit* mode, select the tip and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> > *Hook to Selected Object Bone*:

[image]

This makes the bone the controller of the vertex, of course it probably needs a vertex with its controller at the middle as well:

[image]